# How can I send an array of string from C# to client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

How can I send an array of string from ASP.NET(C#) to javascript using the jQuery ajax technique ??

I know how to do it for a normal string, but i need to implement it with an array of string.

can I use the '`Response.Write`' with an array ?? if yes, then how can I read it from the client side ?? how can i read array from there ??

this is from server side :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };


            Response.Write(arr1);
            Response.End();

    }
```

This is from the client side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(':button').click(function(){

var text_result = "ok"

$.post('default.aspx', { text_res: text_result} , function(data){

alert("The result is: "+data);

}).error(function(){

    alert("Error is occured");

});

});


});
```

this is not working(for array), but its working for normal data
Thanks alot

Comment: Use JSON : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx**

Comment: 'I know how to do it with normal string' - I'm not so sure you do.  It seems that you're just returning strings with the `text/html` content type (since you're doing `Response.Write`); which is **not the same** as returning string data to a javascript client, which typically goes back as [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**Front end**

```
var ID  = 1;
     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "defaut.aspx/GetCoolArray",
                        data: "{ID:" + ID + "}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            var arrayresult = new Array();
                            arrayresult = msg.d;
                            // Do whatever with this cool array
                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            alert(msg.status +" : "+ msg.statusText);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

**Back end**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCoolArray(string ID)
{
    string[] rValue = new string[2];
    rValue[0] = "Cool array element 1";
    rValue[1] = "Cool array element 2";
    return rValue;
}
```

Comment: +1 the only answer so far to actually get this right - should be using JSON!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `string.Join` method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
   string result=String.Join(",",arr1);
   Response.Write(result);
   Response.End();
}
```

This will send the result back to client as  `"one, two, three"`

And in your client Side code, you can get it and then apply the `split` function and you will get an array.

```
$(function () {  
   $(':button').click(function(){
       var text_result="ok";
       $.post("@Url.Action(defaut.aspx/GetCoolArray",
                                      { text_res: text_result}function(msg) {
            var arr=msg.split(",");
            $.each(arr,function(index,item){
                   alert(item);
            });
       });
   });
});
```

You can also Send the DATA as `JSON` to the client. You may use `JavaScriptSerializer` /`JSON.NET` library to do so.  In that case, you may return a valid `JSON` like this

```
[
    "One",
    "Two",
    "three"
]
```

If you are simply **GETting** some data, you may use the `getJSON` method.

```
  $.getJSON("",function(msg){
      $.each(msg,function(index,item){
          alert(item)
      }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer dependes on what are going to do with those strings. If you want to print them, then just use `string.Join(", ", arr1)`. If you want to process them, the best way will be serializing them as a JSON object (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx))

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure you can't. What I usually do when I have to send a dictionary or an array from server to client, I create a string and separate all the elements from an array with | in your case it would be "one|two|three" just remember to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() on each element so it won't have a escape character to break your data.

```
    string strReturn = string.Empty;
    foreach(string strArray in arr1)
    {
       strReturn += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strArray) + "|";
    }
    Response.Write(strReturn.Substring(0, strReturn.Length - 1);
```

And on client :

```
    function(data) {
      data = (data || "");
      var arrData = unescape(data).split('|');
    }
```